# Doesn't complete if statement properly

Tags: c, if-statement, getch

I want this code to:

```
IF unsaved packets is greater or = 1,
then
print "There are unsaved packets"
      "Would you like to saved them?"
      "Type Y for Yes or N for No"
Get user input
      IF User input = Y then function save
 ELSE IF User input = N then exit
      ELSE Return to menue
```

here is my current code, the problem is it won't take the input at all and if it does it doesn't use it to determine what happens after.

```
if(unsavedPackets >= 1)
{
    puts("There are currently unsaved packets in the memory");
    puts("\nWould you like to save them?");
    puts("\nType Y for Yes or N for No");
    getch(saveChoice);
    printf("%c", saveChoice);
    if(saveChoice == "Y")
    {
        puts("Saving records");
        save(recordCount, records);
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(saveChoice == "N")
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Returning to main menu");
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: I think you wanted `saveChoice = getch()` and not `getch(saveChoice)`.

Comment: This would have also worked, thanks!

Comment: `getch(saveChoice)` _should_ have given you a warning (or error).  Whatever compiler you are using, enable more of its warning settings.  You will save time.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that

```
 saveChoice == "Y"
```

where you should write

```
saveChoice == 'Y'
```

Similarly for "N"

In the first case, you are comparing `char` with `const char *` where second is pointer, not a character.

Your `break` statement will always be executed no matter `if` condition is true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

```
if(savechoice =="Y")
```

it should be

```
if(savechoice == 'Y')
```

and likewise for 'N', since you are using **char** variable for storing user inputs.

Comment: It should, else try with gets(savechoice) and then in your if conditions, use if(savechoice[0]=='Y') , likewise for N( make savechoice a string variable)

Comment: Thank you, I have now got it working! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with your `if` statement and also `else if` statement.

```
if(saveChoice == "Y")
and
else if(saveChoice == "N")
```

You are comparing a `char` with a `string`. You have to compare with `char` with a `char` like this
    `if(saveChoice == 'Y')` and `else if(saveChoice == 'N')`

Always remember `single quote for single character`!!!